# How to mine with Intel HD Graphics 4000?

Tags: gpu, cgminer

I'd like to mine with my Intel [HD Graphics 4000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics#History) (128SP 16C 350 MHz/1 GHz, 1.8 GB DDR3 1.6 GHz 64-bit, Integrated Graphics). I think it has support for [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), as I ran benchmark software, and it said it has.

So I tried to use [CGMiner](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/CGMiner) on Windows in the single pool mode:

```
cgminer -o http://pool:port -u username -p password
```

But it said it could not find any devices:

```
 cgminer version 3.8.5 - Started: [2013-12-25 13:41:02]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (5s):0.000 (avg):0.000h/s | A:0  R:0  HW:0  WU:0.0/m
 ST: 2  SS: 0  NB: 2  LW: 5  GF: 0  RF: 0
 Connected to dogepool.pw diff 16 with stratum as user Zignd.igor
 Block: f190f72c...  Diff:472  Started: [13:41:07]  Best share: 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 [2013-12-25 13:41:00] Started cgminer 3.8.5
 [2013-12-25 13:41:01] No devices detected!
 [2013-12-25 13:41:01] Waiting for USB hotplug devices or press q to quit
 [2013-12-25 13:41:01] Probing for an alive pool
 [2013-12-25 13:41:02] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 16
 [2013-12-25 13:41:02] Network diff set to 472
 [2013-12-25 13:41:07] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The latest cgminer no longer supports GPU mining -- it is now exclusively for ASIC mining.

Here is the old 3.7.2 version, which is the last one to support GPU:
http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/3.7/